# How to use multiple particle types in a particle system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, groups

I created a particle system, duplicating a red sphere. However I want to also have yellow and orange spheres (already have them in another layer) in the same particle system. So I want to know how to use this particle system that I've created to show all three kinds of geometry/objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will first need to select the objects you want to use, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to create a group.

Then use the *Groups* setting under *Particle Systems > Render*.

[image]

First, select the `Group` render type:

[image]

Then select the group you want to use:

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to have different colors you could also achieve this with the cycles materials. A node wiring like this picks randomly a color from a color ramp:

[image]

This way the number of particles having a distinct color can be easily controlled by the ramp settings.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I could use that in future! The OP was, however, was asking how to use multiple current objects in one particle system.